# How to build a unit test for test Firebase Dynamic Link

Tags: java, android, android-testing, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to automate the test of consuming a `Firebase Dynamic Link`.

The app responds well from any valid dynamic link that i open from an email but to test it, i need to open the url from my test code.

How can i do it? Loading the url doesn't trigger Android to open my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution pass by using ActivityTestRule, like this:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class TestYard {

    //assign these test rule to the test
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule testRule = new ActivityTestRule(false,false); 


    @Test
    public void testDynamicLink() {

        //Dynamic link url
        String url = "https://....app.goo.gl/...";

        //create intent
        Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData (Uri.parse(url));

        //launch activity with the url as intent. Should work exactly as open from the email generated by Firebase invite function.
        testRule.launchActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Check how to prepare the app [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive?authuser=0).

Comment: Perfect answer, in my case I used an emulator without google play api and for this reason this didnt work for me. So only like a small comment you have to ensure the emulator has this api.